# How to compile sources on MAC OS in 2017?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, compiling

I know there are a few questions like this on the stack already, but currently I'm facing issues with a compilation. I've tried an official guide from the github for mac os, but end up with a lot of errors.
First of all, I always get this kind of errors:

```
aclocal: error: aclocal: file '/usr/local/share/aclocal/introspection.m4' does not exist
```

and other files from aclocal.

If you have an experience, and know how to setup, or know any guides, please share share. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you install all pre-requisites while following the guide? Please provide a link to the guide you're using.

Comment: Have you installed all of the dependencies? Have you followed there instructions: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md?

Comment: Yes, I've followed this guide step by step, all pre-requisites installed as well. ./autogen.sh was throwing alot of aclocal errors, a lot of files not found

Answer (score 3):

On a Mac Pro with MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 I got a clean compilation by following the instructions in [`doc/build-osx.md`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md).

The sequence of commands is:

1) First install Xcode and HomeBrew by executing (in [Terminal](https://www.wikihow.com/Open-a-Terminal-Window-in-Mac))

```
xcode-select --install

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

2) Then install required libraries with

```
brew install automake berkeley-db4 libtool boost --c++11 miniupnpc openssl pkg-config protobuf qt libevent python3
```

(note: I added python3 otherwise there would be errors during "make check")

3) Download and compile

```
git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin
cd bitcoin
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make check
```

Comment: --c++11 not necessary anymore on Macos

Answer (score 0):

Searching `aclocal: error: aclocal: file` on google yields https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/3335

the last comment yields

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26748352/6557621

```
brew doctor
brew prune
```